# Check input of DataGridView cell while writing

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to check if DataGridView cell contain number between 0 and 3 while entering value?

This is how I check if specific cell constains int number:

```
 private void dgUpitnik_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(ColumnOcjena_KeyPress);
        if (dgUpitnik.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2) //Desired Column
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(ColumnOcjena_KeyPress);
            }

        }
    }

    private void ColumnOcjena_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }            
    }
```

But how to check inside KeyPress event that the number entered in cell is 0, 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: If values of cell must be only 0 or 1 or 2 or 3, then maybe `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` will be better approach

Comment: I've tought about that but in my case requirement is to have DataGridTextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution, here it is:

```
 private void dgUpitnik_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        dgUpitnik.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
        int newInteger;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            if (dgUpitnik.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out newInteger) || newInteger > 3)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    dgUpitnik.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Ocjena mora biti u rasponu od 0 do 3!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe it will be usable for someone someday.